# Ruby grocery list program

Tags: ruby

I am currently learning Ruby and I'm trying to write a simple Ruby `grocery_list` method. Here are the instructions:

We want to write a program to help keep track of a grocery list. It takes a grocery item (like "eggs") as an argument, and returns the grocery list (that is, the item names with the quantities of each item). If you pass the same argument twice, it should increment the quantity.

```
def grocery_list(item)
  array = []
  quantity = 1
  array.each {|x| quantity += x }
  array << "#{quantity}" + " #{item}"
end

puts grocery_list("eggs", "eggs")
```

so I'm trying to figure out here how to return "2 eggs" by passing eggs twice

Comment: should it also consider other items? for example, what should be the output of `puts grocery_list("eggs", "beer", "milk", "eggs")`?

Comment: yes it should consider other items as well, can be anything on a grocery list. So that output would be 2 eggs, beer, milk

Comment: You might find it easier to use a hash.

Comment: Same thing as on your other post; I am locking it for now, and expect no further edits of the kind that were done here. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To help you count the different items you can use as Hash.  A Hash is similar to an Array, but with Strings instead of Integers als an Index:

```
a = Array.new
a[0] = "this"
a[1] = "that"

h = Hash.new
h["sonja"] = "asecret"
h["brad"] = "beer"
```

In this example the Hash might be used for storing passwords for users.  But for your
example you need a hash for counting.  Calling grocery_list("eggs", "beer", "milk", "eggs")
should lead to the following commands being executed:

```
h = Hash.new(0)   # empty hash {} created, 0 will be default value
h["eggs"] += 1    # h is now {"eggs"=>1}
h["beer"] += 1    # {"eggs"=>1, "beer"=>1}
h["milk"] += 1    # {"eggs"=>1, "beer"=>1, "milk"=>1}
h["eggs"] += 1    # {"eggs"=>2, "beer"=>1, "milk"=>1}
```

You can work through all the keys and values of a Hash with the each-loop:

```
h.each{|key, value|  .... }
```

and build up the string we need as a result, adding
the number of items if needed, and the name of the item.
Inside the loop we always add a comma and a blank at the end.
This is not needed for the last element, so after the
loop is done we are left with

```
"2 eggs,  beer,  milk, "
```

To get rid of the last comma and blank we can use chop!, which "chops off"
one character at the end of a string:

```
output.chop!.chop!
```

One more thing is needed to get the complete implementation of your grocery_list:
you specified that the function should be called like so:

```
puts grocery_list("eggs",  "beer", "milk","eggs")
```

So the grocery_list function does not know how many arguments it's getting. We can handle
this by specifying one argument with a star in front, then this argument will
be an array containing all the arguments:

```
def grocery_list(*items)
   # items is an array
end
```

So here it is: I did your homework for you and implemented grocery_list.
I hope you actually go to the trouble of understanding the implementation,
and don't just copy-and-paste it.

```
def grocery_list(*items)
  hash = Hash.new(0)
  items.each {|x| hash[x] += 1}

  output = ""
  hash.each do |item,number| 
     if number > 1 then 
       output += "#{number} " 
     end
     output += "#{item}, "
  end

  output.chop!.chop!
  return output
end

puts grocery_list("eggs",  "beer", "milk","eggs")
# output: 2 eggs,  beer,  milk
```

Comment: This is super helpful, thank you. My aim is not to copy but to understand what each line of code is doing. Thanks for the descriptions.

Comment: can you explain output.chop!.chop!  ??

Comment: @ajhalbrook This is a method of removing the last two characters from a string.  See the docs for it here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-chop-21

Comment: and why did you do that exactly? which 2 characters are you chopping? I ran it in Ruby without the output.chop!.chop! and it returned the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
def grocery_list(*item)
  item.group_by{|i| i}
end

p grocery_list("eggs", "eggs","meat")
#=> {"eggs"=>["eggs", "eggs"], "meat"=>["meat"]}

def grocery_list(*item)
  item.group_by{|i| i}.flat_map{|k,v| [k,v.length]}
end

p grocery_list("eggs", "eggs","meat")
#=>["eggs", 2, "meat", 1] 

def grocery_list(*item)
  Hash[*item.group_by{|i| i}.flat_map{|k,v| [k,v.length]}]
end

grocery_list("eggs", "eggs","meat")
#=> {"eggs"=>2, "meat"=>1}

grocery_list("eggs", "eggs","meat","apple","apple","apple") 
#=> {"eggs"=>2, "meat"=>1, "apple"=>3}
```

or as @Lee said:

```
def grocery_list(*item)
  item.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|a, h| h[a] += 1 }
end

grocery_list("eggs", "eggs","meat","apple","apple","apple") 
#=> {"eggs"=>2, "meat"=>1, "apple"=>3}
```

Comment: `items.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|a, h| h[a] += 1 }`

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful since you use the splat operator and some enumerable methods.

Comment: @Priti Just noticed your `inject` edit. See my comment above, `inject/reduce` was not made for this, doing `;h` tells you why. `each_with_object` was

Comment: @Priti can you break the code down and explain what each part is doing? Since I'm a newbie!

Comment: or is there any way to modify my code a little to make it work? I'm just looking for a more basic answer at the moment although your methods are great.

Comment: @Priti He is new to Ruby, what are you doing is too advanced IMHO.

Comment: @NielsB. Here we always try to give some rubyistic solution. And I did the same. Now It is his responsibility yo read the documentation and understand what I did.

Comment: **Down-voter** - where is the problem with this code? why it is down-voted. If you are confident enough,come forward to tell the same.

Comment: @Priti I disagree. You are giving him four different solutions with no explanation besides return values, which themselves are confusing to comprehend if you are not familiar with Ruby.

Your solutions are excellent, terse and readable for a seasoned rubyist, but too much for a beginner. His responsibility is to grasp one concept at a time, not five.

Comment: @NielsB. I think you should open your eyes and look closely,that I have given him only 2 solutions, and first one I broke into 4 parts to show the internal operations.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more verbose, but perhaps more readable solutions to your challenge.

```
def grocery_list(*items) # Notice the asterisk in front of items. It means "put all the arguments into an array called items"
  my_grocery_hash = {}  # Creates an empty hash

  items.each do |item| # Loops over the argument array and passes each argument into the loop as item.
     if my_grocery_hash[item].nil? # Returns true of the item is not a present key in the hash...
       my_grocery_hash[item] = 1 # Adds the key and sets the value to 1.
     else
       my_grocery_hash[item] = my_grocery_hash[item] + 1 # Increments the value by one.
     end
  end
  my_grocery_hash # Returns a hash object with the grocery name as the key and the number of occurences as the value.
end
```

This will create an empty hash (called dictionaries or maps in other languages) where each grocery is added as a key with the value set to one. In case the same grocery appears multiple times as a parameter to your method, the value is incremented.

If you want to create a text string and return that instead of the hash object and you can do like this after the iteration:

```
grocery_list_string = "" # Creates an empty string

my_grocery_hash.each do |key, value| # Loops over the hash object and passes two local variables into the loop with the current entry. Key being the name of the grocery and value being the amount.
  grocery_list_string << "#{value} units of #{key}\n" # Appends the grocery_list_string. Uses string interpolation, so #{value} becomes 3 and #{key} becomes eggs. The remaining \n is a newline character.
end

return grocery_list_string # Explicitly declares the return value. You can ommit return.
```

Updated answer to comment:

If you use the first method without adding the hash iteration you will get a hash object back which can be used to look up the amount like this.

```
my_hash_with_grocery_count = grocery_list("Lemonade", "Milk", "Eggs", "Lemonade", "Lemonade")

my_hash_with_grocery_count["Milk"]
--> 1

my_hash_with_grocery_count["Lemonade"]
--> 3
```

Comment: OK, so for your first method to get the value I would put grocery_list("eggs", "milk", "eggs") and this would return 2 eggs, 1 milk?

Comment: okay, SO doesn't like code in comments. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I should've been more specific. The list with the grocery items and the count of each item..not 'value' -- Thanks, this helps a lot

Comment: The question is: Do you want a string or do you want an object? If you want a string, you have to add the second block of code after going through items.

Answer (score 1):

### Use a Hash Instead of an Array

When you want an easy want to count things, you can use a hash key to hold the name of the thing you want to count, and the value of that key is the quantity. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class GroceryList
  attr_reader :list

  def initialize
    # Specify hash with default quantity of zero.
    @list = Hash.new(0)
  end

  # Increment the quantity of each item in the @list, using the name of the item
  # as a hash key.
  def add_to_list(*items)
    items.each { |item| @list[item] += 1 }
    @list
  end
end

if $0 == __FILE__
  groceries = GroceryList.new
  groceries.add_to_list('eggs', 'eggs') 
  puts 'Grocery list correctly contains 2 eggs.' if groceries.list['eggs'] == 2
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`Enumerable#each_with_object` can be useful for things like this:

```
def list_to_hash(*items)
  items.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |item, list| list[item] += 1 }
end

def hash_to_grocery_list_string(hash)
  hash.each_with_object([]) do |(item, number), result|
    result << (number > 1 ? "#{number} #{item}" : item)
  end.join(', ')
end

def grocery_list(*items)
  hash_to_grocery_list_string(list_to_hash(*items))
end

p grocery_list('eggs', 'eggs', 'bread', 'milk', 'eggs')

# => "3 eggs, bread, milk"
```

It iterates an array or hash to enable building another object in a convenient way.  The `list_to_hash` method uses it to build a hash from the items array (the splat operator converts the method arguments to an array); the hash is created so that each value is initialized to 0.  The `hash_to_grocery_list_string` method uses it to build an array of strings that is joined to a comma-separated string.